# AWK - How to easily define a customized list of values and loop through it?

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, awk

First of all, I am looking for a simpler way of doing it rather than debugging an issue here.

I know that, in AWK, we can loop through values like this:

```
echo "hello world" |awk '{for (t=1; t<=10; t++) print t, $0}'
```

But now I need to loop through some customized values, for example, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 10, 30, 50, 70, 90, 100, 300, 500, 700, 900. What worked for me is something like this:

```
echo "hello world" |awk 'BEGIN{t_values[1]=1; t_values[3]=1, t_values[5]=1, ... t_values[700]=1, t_values[900]=1} {for (t in t_values) print t, $0}'
```

However, that's a lot of typing and error-prone. Is there a simpler way to do it? For example, define a list of values like `t_values=[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, ..., 700, 900]` and then loop through it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass comma separated value and use split:

```
awk -v t_values='1,3,5,7,9,700,900' 'BEGIN {
  n = split(t_values, vals, /,/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print vals[i]}'
```

```
1
3
5
7
9
700
900
```

If you want to define variable inside `awk` then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{t_values="1,3,5,7,9,700,900";
n = split(t_values, vals, /,/); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print vals[i]}'
```